# is it possible to build applications specific to an earlier android version when currently i have a much newer version?

Tags: android, webview, widget, version, compatibility

I'm currently trying the webview widget in a very old version of android sdk version 7(android 2.1). My code is working fine in this widget but when i try in another model(android 4.3) the webview doesn't work properly.

Is it possible to somehow ensure that the latest android(4.3) to run as perfectly as in the earlier android?

Thanks,
Dexter

Comment: that is not funny. if its not possible, just say it can't be done. i thought sarcasm if not encouraged here.

Comment: Sorry, I must have been in a bad mood yesterday :) Please, consider posting some relevant code (including the HTML part).